# Firebase - not getting the right length from my maps

Tags: jquery, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to display the name of a record. This is working fine.
But, below the widget containing the name, I want to display the number of items contained in the array.
Right now, I am only getting the # of records in the collection. I have tried different things, but I can not get the length of the array. Please, can you advise? Many thanks

[image]

[image]

```
     body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height /1.4,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child:StreamBuilder(
              stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection('Users')
                  .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)
                  .collection('lists')
                  .snapshots(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot){
                
                QuerySnapshot data = snapshot.requireData;
                
                return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: data.size,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index){
                    Map item = data.docs[index].data();
                   
                    print('items');
                    print (item);
          
                      return InkWell(
                        child: Card(
                            child: ListTile(
                              leading: Icon(Icons.skip_next_rounded),
                              title:Text((item['listName'])),
                              subtitle: Text(item.length.toString())), //This is were I want to display the # of records
                            ),
                      onTap:(){
                              Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DetailScreen_CheckList_V3(item['listName']),));

                  },
                );
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just find the solution finaly.

```
child: ListTile(
  leading: Icon(Icons.skip_next_rounded),
  title:Text((item['listName'])),
  subtitle: Text(item['allItems'].length.toString())),
),
```